# How to create MassAction like "update attributes"?

Tags: magento2

I created an mass action via this link: https://magecomp.com/blog/magento-2-add-custom-mass-action-in-product-grid/

And it works perfectly, however you get a different type of action than I want to create.

This is the type of mass action I have now:

[image: This is the type of mass action I have now]

And what I want is to open a new page just like on update attributes and then you can add attributes you need.

Where can I find .xml file and is there something I need to look out for? Link to a project that does the same would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to Add Custom Mass Action in Product Grid in Magento 2:

Step 1: Go to the following path:

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_listing.xml

Step 2: After that, create the MassSalable.php file at the below path:

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\MassSalable.php

Details can be found at: https://magecomp.com/blog/magento-2-add-custom-mass-action-in-product-grid/